# Passkeys versus passwords for intranet websites

Tags: authentication, passwords, web-application, webauthn

Do passkeys offer more security for intranet websites compared to passwords?

I know there are additional methods like 2FA to get more security, but I just want to look at a optional replacement for simple password-based authentication over https. Another assumption is that Windows Hello on the workstations is used as authenticator and no hardware security token.

I'm worried about the cloud synchronization of the passkeys (Google, Apple, etc.), that would be fine for a Google account, but for an intranet website? Do the advantages of passkeys outweigh this disadvantage, or are there other things to consider?